# "Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist" for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, content-script

I am trying to create a chrome extension that sends the DOM body from the active tab to some backend server, which will return some response which I will do later.  However, I cannot figure out how send information via event listeners from the content-script to the service-worker. Heres the code I have now:
Service-Worker:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "submit") {
      console.log("submit stage 1")
      const response_tabs = sendMessageToActiveTab('sendDOM')
      console.log(response_tabs)
      const response_runtime = chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: 'sendDOM', action: 'sendDOM'})
      console.log(response_runtime)


async function sendMessageToActiveTab(message) {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true });
  const response = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {message: message, action: 'sendDOM'});
  return response
}
```

Content-Script:

```
chrome.tabs.addListener(async function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "sendDOM") {
    const article = await document.querySelector("body");
    console.log("article: ", article);
    sendResponse(article);
    return article;
  }
});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender) {
  if (message.action === "sendDOM") {
    const article = await document.querySelector("body");
    console.log("article: ", article);
    sendResponse(article);
    return article;
  }
});
```

And manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Nuntia",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["activeTab","tabs"],  
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://*.google.com/*"]
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Any advice on how to go about doing this or fixing my approach would be greatly appreciated!

So far I have tried different ways to make the two js files communicate with each other such as chrome.tabs and chrome.runtime.  Both are returning this same error

Comment: 1) Remove the entire chrome.tabs.addListener block from the content script. 2) You can't send DOM elements via messaging. Send the element's textContent or innerHTML. 3) Remove `await` 4) You need to [re-inject content scripts explicitly](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension. 5) Don't use ChatGPT.

Comment: 5) Don't use ChatGPT. <- This

Answer (score 1):

[`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage) accepts as the last argument a callback which is called when the other end executes `sendResponse` (the third parameter to the [`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-sendMessage) callback).

The same goes for `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. Also, there is no `chrome.tabs.addListener`.

So, to send messages from the content script, you'll do something like this:

[the background service].

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((sender, message, sendResponse) => {
  ...
});
```

[content script]

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ something: 'to be sent' }, (response) => {
  ...
});
```

Then, the background script will process the message and call.

```
sendResponse({ message: 'processed' });
```

Which will trigger the function passed as the second argument to `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` in the content script and `response` will be `{ message: 'processed' }`

About `Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist`.
That can happen in a few situations.

The most common one is if inside the callback to `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` you perform and async task and then call `sendResponse`.

To prevent that, you need to return `true` from this callback:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((sender, message, sendResponse) => {
  setTimeout(() => sendResponse({..}), 1000);
  return true;
});
```

This informs the system that `sendResponse` will be called after the callback function returns.